# DataFrame.fillna method - filling the NaN values with Df.mean(axis =1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to fill my dataframe's NaN values through fillna method:

[image]

after applying the fill na with value = df.mean(axis =1) I am still getting some NaN values in some columns

[image]

can anyone explain how is it filling up the NaN values

Comment: what happens if you try simply `df.fillna(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Fills all NaN with the df.mean of a column values.

Given df,

```
       0      1      2      3      4
0  804.0  271.0  690.0  401.0  158.0
1  352.0  995.0  770.0  616.0  791.0
2  381.0  824.0   61.0  152.0    NaN
3  907.0  607.0    NaN  488.0  180.0
4  981.0  938.0  378.0  957.0  176.0
5    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Output:

```
       0      1       2      3       4
0  804.0  271.0  690.00  401.0  158.00
1  352.0  995.0  770.00  616.0  791.00
2  381.0  824.0   61.00  152.0  326.25
3  907.0  607.0  474.75  488.0  180.00
4  981.0  938.0  378.00  957.0  176.00
5  685.0  727.0  474.75  522.8  326.25
```